# Nested divs of same class, show child on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show a hidden div on hover of its parent.
My issue is that there are nested divs of the same class, and when I hover an "inner" div, its parent is also hovered and both their hidden children are shown.
html:

```
<div class="a_class">
    lorem ipsum
    <div class="inner">
        <a href="">hidden...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="b_class">
        blahblah<br />
        <div class="a_class">
            <div class="inner">
                <a href="">hidden...</a>
            </div>
            lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.inner{display:none;}
.a_class:hover > .inner{display: block;}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nb6tD/

In other words, i'm trying to achieve this: when i hover over the second .a_class, only the .inner under it should show up, not the .inner under the "parent" .a_class.

Is it possible only with css?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT: the answer**
So, it appears it CAN'T be done with pure css, unless the html markup changes - which is not possible in my case.
I wished for a css3-magic solution, but since there's no such option, i'm going javascript.

I accepted the most suitable solution though for future reference, for all out there that have the possibility of changing the html structure.

Comment: how many nested element can you have? only two levels?

Comment: For now yes, two levels

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can "fix" this without changing the html structure - you could have an element enclosing the hoverable area and its corresponding button:

Here, i've added a `.hoverArea` div. (Extra div not needed on the innermost one, as it only contains a single `.inner`)

#### html

```
<div class="a_class">
    <div class="hoverArea">
        lorem ipsum
        <div class="inner">
            <a href="">hidden...</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="b_class">
        blahblah<br />
        <div class="a_class hoverArea">
            <div class="inner">
                <a href="">hidden...</a>
            </div>
            lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### css

```
.hoverArea:hover > .inner{
    display: block;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Nb6tD/7/

Comment: Changing the html is not an option in my case, but thanks for answering. I wished there was a super-magic new css3 solution, since not, i'll use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

In this way? (needs some HTML changes)

http://jsfiddle.net/Nb6tD/6/

```
i {
    display: none;
}

.trick:hover >  i {
   display: inline;
}
```

Comment: I don't want anything. The OP wants. LOL

Comment: now it works, I hope. And someone has found the same solution before me, ook

Comment: You're not even taking into consideration the OP HTML markup. Are you sure you've read the question?

Comment: yes and without JS is not possible, it's like asking to a cow to fly without put on its back wings. He needs a CSS parent selector, which in CSS doesn't exist

Comment: I'm aware of that. But if you're proposing a solution that involves HTML markup changes, you need to mention it on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with pure css because you are hovering on the parent element as well as the `.a_class` child element then ofcourse it will show you both the blocks.

If you can change the html to some extent then it can be achieved easily.

The changes I have done to html are:

- I wrapped the complete html code in `.block` class element.
- closed the parent `.a_class` before starting of the `.b_class` element.

---

**CSS**

```
.block, .block .b_class>.a_class {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nb6tD/3/)

Comment: @AndreaLigios no man it is goku, a cartoon character from Dragon ball Z. I am a fan of him :). Credit goes to some anonymous artist from deviantart.com.

Comment: I know DBZ :) just wondering if you were the artist. Btw good stuff from deviantart as usual :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Changing the html is not possible in my case, so javascript is the way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that as the second set are nested inside the first `.a_class`, in effect the first `.a_class` is still being hovered over when you hover over the second `.a_class`.

So at that time both elements are interpreted as being hovered, which will trigger the behaviour that is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It Works for me

You just need to point or access exact tag or class in inner child where you want to apply your css
e.g:

```css
.footer-custom-icons li:hover >  .iconlist-item-icon i, 
.footer-custom-icons li:hover > .iconlist-item-content p a 
{
   color: white !important;
}
```